# Typescript global namespace declarations

Tags: typescript, namespaces, cypress

I'm using Cypress in my tests and it's included a file that declare the module type configurations.

```
declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
        helpers: any
        getAndFocus: string
        clickSearchResult: number
    }
```

I want to use my own custom `helpers` type

```
import { HelpersType } from "../types/support"

declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
        helpers: HelpersType
        getAndFocus: string
        clickSearchResult: number
    }

}
```

As soon as I add that import statement the `declare namespace` stops working and I see the error `'Cypress' is declared but its value is never read`, and any other custom type related to `Cypress` stops working altogether.

Why does this happen? And is there a way I can import my custom type here?

Should I declare my custom type here and just export it?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a workaround, I can just import inside the declare namespace closure and it'll work as expected.

I'm still not sure why this works or if this is even recommended.

```
declare namespace Cypress {
    import { HelpersType } from '../types/support'
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
        helpers: HelpersType
    }

}
```

Comment: This is how you do it; otherwiise, the file is considered a module and not an ambient declaration file.